# extracting information from file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file like:

```
number_of_x     100 # total number of x
number_of_y     2000 # total number of y
total_rate     1.67 # rate
blah1     0.876 # blah1
blah2     10450 # blah2
```

I would like to extract numbers related to, say, `number_of_y` and `total_rate`, for example, output here is:

```
2000
1.67
```

This is the closest I can get:

```
grep -E 'number_of_y|total_rate' my_file | grep -Eo '[0-9.]*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe awk will be helpful:

```
grep -E 'number_of_y|total_rate' my_file | awk '{print $2}'
```

Change `$2` on whatever column you would like to show

Comment: Why not just `awk '/number_of_y|total_rate/ {print $2}' my_file`?

Comment: @steeldriver inded its faster